# Good way to convert Optional<Integer> to Optional<Long>

Tags: java, java-7, guava, option-type

I am trying to find a clean and  code-efficient way to convert `Optional<Integer>` to `Optional<Long>`. I am working in Java 7 with Guava.

So in one place in the code I have an optional integer created

```
    Optional<Integer> optionalInt = Optional.fromNullable(someInt);
```

And in another area I need it as an optional long.
The nicest thing I could come up with is this:

```
    Optional<Long> optionalLong = optionalInt.transform(new Function<Integer, Long>() {
        @Override
        public Long apply(Integer inputInt) {
            if (inputInt != null)
                return inputInt.longValue();
            else
                return null;
        }
    });
```

But this is cumbersome, especially if you consider how easy it was to cast the type when I was using primitive types.

Any good ideas out there?

Comment: Use Java 8 it is just `optionalInt.map(i -> (long) i);`

Comment: In your function, you don't have to test for `null`: `Optional.absent().transform(...)` does nothing.

Comment: @PeterLawrey or `optionalInt.map(Integer::longValue)`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## TL;DR: In Java 7, No.

Sadly this is the best Java 7 has to offer in terms of support for functions.

I would just say that `transform` will never be called with `null` so you can do:

```
Optional<Long> optionalLong = optionalInt.transform(new Function<Integer, Long>() {
    @Override
    public Long apply(Integer inputInt) {
        return inputInt.longValue();
    }
});
```

From [the documentation](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Optional.html#transform(com.google.common.base.Function)):

> If the instance is present, it is transformed with the given
>   `Function`; otherwise, `absent()` is returned. If the function returns
>   `null`, a `NullPointerException` is thrown.

So **never** return `null` from a `Function` passed to `transform`.

If you reuse this a lot, then you could use the `enum` singleton pattern:

```
public enum IntToLong implements Function<Integer, Long> {

    INSTANCE;

    @Override
    public Long apply(Integer input) {
        return input.longValue();
    }
}
```

Then:

```
optionalInt.transform(IntToLong.INSTANCE);
```

This obviously reduces the code at the call site at the expense of having extra classes in the code base - something I wouldn't be too worried about.

Answer (score 3):

close to the cast:

```
Optional<Long> optionalLong = Optional.fromNullable(optionalInt.isPresent() ?
     optionalInt.get().longValue() : null);
```

basically this avoids the overhead of invoking transform. Invoking isPresent could be simplified to checking the value for null directly.

Comment: Why not  `= optionalInt.isPresent() ? Optional.of(optionalInt.get().longValue()) : Optional.absent()`. This avoids the `null` - which is exactly what `Optional` is supposed to do. I'm not sure "overhead" is the right word here either - maybe "complexity".